# Compare date in specific format in LINQ

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

i often compare date this way by in-line sql.

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.tbl_MyTable
WHERE 
CONVERT(VARCHAR, DateTimeValueColumn, 112) >= CONVERT(VARCHAR, '20150101', 112) AND
CONVERT(VARCHAR, DateTimeValueColumn, 112) <= CONVERT(VARCHAR, '20150201', 112)
```

how could i instruct LINQ to generate the above SQL for date comparison. looking for sample code to achieve this. thanks

Comment: Go get a tool like LINQpad, do the conversion to linq and you can easily see the sql that the linq will produce.

Comment: is it possible to translate sql to linq by LINQpad tool ?

Comment: Dates have no format, they are binary values. If `DateTimeValueColumn` is a `date` or `datetime` there's no reason to convert anything, just compare it directly, eg: `DateTimeValueColumn>='20150101'`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos there is a subtle difference when using the `<=` operator. DateTimeValueColumn <= ' 20150201` would NOT include dates on the 2015-02-01, unless the time part is 00:00:00.

Comment: Then simply cast the column to `date` or compare with the next date. String conversions are evil because the prevent the database from using any indexes.

Comment: @Mou To convert SQL to LINQ take a look at http://www.sqltolinq.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would have been easier to answer if you actually told wanted to do: comparing only the dart part of timestamps. You convert them to format 112 (`yyyyMMdd`) in order to achieve that.

If you use LINQ queries you'll get `DateTime` objects for `datetime` or `datetime2` columns. To compare the date part you can simply use the `Date` property of the `DateTime` objects, e.g.

```
[...]
where row.DateTimeColumn.Date >= new DateTime(2015, 1, 1) &&
      row.DateTimeColumn.Date <= new DateTime(2015, 2, 1)
```